# Module did not self-register. Electron app using a custom build c++ node module compiled with cmake-js

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, cmake, electron

Working on a project. Built a C++ module for node, compiled it with cmake. I tried using the module in my main electron app but it errors out.

Reproduced it with a minimal repo here: https://github.com/Aerrus/electronMinimal

```
 App threw an error during load
Error: Module did not self-register.
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:160:31)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:160:31)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:640:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at bindings     (C:\Users\xxx\electronMinimal\mods\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\electronMinimal\mods\index.js:1:188)
```

Saw a lot of threads already about rebuilding it, making sure the node version when I built it was the same, and so on. None of them changed anything.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows. Building for x64

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using electron v4.0
take a look at this. I hope it helped because that's how I solved the problem

[adding delay hook to cmakelist using cmake-js](https://github.com/cmake-js/cmake-js/issues/153)